# How to append new rows to .RDS file in Rstudio using write() function

Tags: r, file, append

I have an example **myfile.rds** file below:

```
X
firstword
secondword
thirdword
```

I execute the below line in RStudio to append the word 'mytext' text to `myfile.rds` but without overwriting the original contents of 'myfile.rds'.

```
write("mytext", file = "myfile.rds", append = TRUE)
```

**Expected output:**

```
X
firstword
secondword
thirdword
mytext
```

It executes without throwing any error or warning as shown below

```
> write("mytext", file = "myfile.rds", append = TRUE)
>
```

However, when I import the `myfile.rds` dataset to view it the text is not added and I get the following warnings.

```
> myfile <- read.table("D:/.../.../myfile.rds", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
>   View(myfile)
```

On executing `warnings()`, the below warnings are displayed:

```
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(path, encoding = encoding, header = header,  ... :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(path, encoding = encoding, header = header,  ... :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(path, encoding = encoding, header = header,  ... :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(path, encoding = encoding, header = header,  ... :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote,  ... :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
6: 'default.stringsAsFactors' is deprecated.
Use '`stringsAsFactors = FALSE`' instead.
See help("Deprecated")
7: In read.table("D:/.../.../myfile.rds",  ... :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
8: In read.table("D:/.../.../myfile.rds",  ... :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
9: In read.table("D:/.../.../myfile.rds",  ... :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
10: In read.table("D:/.../.../myfile.rds",  ... :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
11: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote,  ... :
  EOF within quoted string
12: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote,  ... :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
>
```

I tried to append the same text to a new `.rds` file and the text is successfully appended. Any suggestion on how I can fix this? Unfortunately I am not in a position
to share the contents of the `myfile.rds` file due to privacy issues.

Comment: File formats are not interchangeable. RDS is a special file format for R. RDS files are created by the `saveRDS` function and read by `readRDS`. Using `write` is a function for writing plain text files. `read.table` is a function for reading in plain text files with specific formatting constraints (rectangular text tables with a specific character delimiting fields). With care, `write` could be used with `read.table`, but you should really just use `write.table` instead. Neither `write` nor `read.table` should be expected to work with RDS files at all.

Comment: I'd suggest reading in the object stored in the RDS file, adding your column, and then overwriting the RDS file with a new version.

Comment: Thanks I tried: write.table("mytext", file = "myfile.rds", append = TRUE) but it simply  overwrites contents of myfile.rds with the word mytext. What I want is to insert the word 'mytext' at the bottom of the contents in 'myfile.rds' file.

Comment: Let's make this reproducible. I run the code `saveRDS(data.frame(X = c("firstword", "secondword", "thirdword")), file = "myfile.rds")` then open the RDS file in a text editor to see what the contents are, I see this: `??b```f`abb`f2XCC?t-?b?@# @0piδ̢?????Wqjr~^ gIFfDh*? ?k^bnj1?@? c????btU\)?%?ziE@Дs??? ?b? ?????@???N??%`. This is what real RDS files look like. This is how R encodes R objects in the RDS file format. Hopefully it's clear that adding `"mytext"` at the bottom of this file is mixing different formats - plain text and RDS, which will result in a file that is unreadable by anything.

Comment: So if you have an RDS file created with `saveRDS` then appending text to the bottom of the file will break the file. Your code does that - it does exactly what you ask, it breaks the file by adding that line. I run `write.table("mytext", file = "myfile.rds", append = TRUE)` and the contents of the file are now `??b```f`abb`f2XCC?t-?b?@# @0piδ̢?????Wqjr~^ gIFfDh*? ?k^bnj1?@? c????btU\)?%?ziE@Дs??? ?b? ?????@???N??% "1" "mytext"`. You can see the appended "mytext" (along with the row number "1" because you used `write.table` on a 1-row data frame).

Comment: RDS files can't be written piecemeal. If you use a plain text format from the start, like CSV or TXT, then you can add lines to the bottom of the file in the same format and things will work. If you use RDS, you cannot add things to the bottom of the file and have things work.

Comment: (Note that RStudio knows what an RDS file is and knows that it is not human readable, so it makes it hard for you to open it to see actual contents. RStudio expects that what you want to do with an RDS file is import the contents to R using `readRDS`, so if you try to open the file in RStudio, it will import it into R. To view the actual contents of the file, I used my OS's command line and viewed it with `cat myfile.rds` which prints the contents of a file as-is. You could also view the file by opening it in another text editor that doesn't know about RDS files, like notepad.)

Comment: Thanks once again. I can open the rds file using RSTUDIO's Import Dataset option from text(base) or from text(readr) . In this way the file contents are displayed in a human  readable format. What I am just curious about is why it is not possible to add contents to an original file. For example if I have a list of words that are considered as blacklists and should be filtered, I may want to add new words that I need to add to the already existing blacklist.

Comment: You are not opening the file, you are importing the file into R. "Import dataset" runs code on the file that knows how to turn the computer-readable contents of the file, which look like `??b```fabbf2XCC?t-?b?@# @0piδ̢?????Wqjr~^ gIFfDh*? ?k^bnj1?@? c????btU\)?%?ziE@Дs??? ?b? ?????@???N??%`, into an R object, and you are viewing the object in R. I don't know how to explain it any more clearly than I have in these comments. You have 2 good options - (a) as in my second comment - read the object into R, make the changes to the R object, and overwrite the entire file with the new, bigger object.

Comment: (b) use a different format than RDS. If you use CSV (with `read.csv` and `write.csv`) or TXT (with `read.table` and `write.table`), then you can use those `write` functions that take `append` arguments to append new words to the bottom of the file.

Comment: But you cannot append to an RDS file and have the file be readable. That won't work. You've tried it, it doesn't work. I've demonstrated it. It doesn't work because RDS files are serialized and not human readable. They weren't designed to be written in pieces. RDS files can hold any R object, not just vectors or data frames. And they have been optimized to minimize disk space and read/write times. This is why they are more complicated. They were not designed to be editable/appendable.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Much appreciate. I ill try to follow your option 2, though it was not very clear to me.

Comment: If you had the R command `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`, you cannot append anything to the end of that to turn it into `x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)` - you need to delete the `)` and add `, 4` and then replace the `)`. It is a more complicated operation. You cannot do it by just appending.

Comment: option (b) is nice and simple: first create the file: `write.csv(mydata, "myfile.csv")`. Read the file: `read.csv("myfile.csv")`. Append to the file: `write.csv(new_data, "myfile.csv", append = TRUE)`. Or if you just need a vector, not a data frame with multiple columns, you could use `write()` and `readLines()`.