# Output after converting RDS file to CSV and back to RDS displays new record as data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, read-csv

My question stems from a previous discussion where I was seeking a solution to append to a *.rds* file using R. However, as explained at length on this thread: [How to append new rows to .RDS file in Rstudio using write() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568004/how-to-append-new-rows-to-rds-file-in-rstudio-using-write-function) it is not possible to do that. I am now attempting a workround by first converting the RDS to CSV:

The RDS file has a single column **X**. I convert the RDS to CSV to allow me to manually add my new record and then convert the CSV back to RDS format, which is the format I need to work with.

**Step 1:**

```
> library(foreign)
```

**Step 2:** I convert the RDS file to CSV

```
> for (f in Sys.glob('*.rds')) 
     write.csv(readRDS(f), file = gsub('rds$', 'csv', f))
```

**Step 3:** I insert the new record at the bottom of the CSV file

```
new_record <- data.frame("D")
write.table(new_record, file = "my_csv_dataframe.csv", append = TRUE, quote = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

**Step 4:** I convert the CSV file back to the RDS format

```
myrdsobject <- read.csv("my_csv_dataframe.csv", header=TRUE)
```

**Step 5:** I save as .rds format

```
saveRDS(myrdsobject, "my_rds_dataframe.rds")
```

**Step 6:** I run the below in Rstudio to display *my_rds_dataframe.rds* and everything looks ok except that the new record, **D** is written as **data.frame** instead of D.

```
> my_rds_dataframe <- read.table("my_rds_dataframe.rds", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
>   View(my_rds_dataframe)
```

As an example after converting the RDS to CSV (Step 2), the output looks as below:

```
"x"
"A"
"B"
"C"
```

When I add a record (Step 3) e.g., "D", the resulting CSV is:

```
"x"
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
```

When I import the RDS file in Rstudio (Step 5) the output appears as:

```
X
A
B
C
data.frame
```

Is there anything that I need to do to display the record *D* in the output instead of *data.frame*. *Unfortunately I am unable to share the actual contents of the original RDS file*.

Comment: I think you left out the important code, how you were doing this inserting.  But why kind of object is this? Is it a data frame or something else?  If your objects are already in the global environment why not add the row to those objects and then resave?

Comment: @Elin: I have added the code on Step 3 on how I insert the new record "D"

Comment: You should not be using read.table() on an rds file. You need to use readRDS()  and you need to make sure to assign it to a name. 
`my_rds_dataframe <- readRDS("my_rds_dataframe.rds") `

Answer (score 1):

using csv is pointless extra work, once you have the data.frame or matrix object loaded from the rds you grow it in memory by row binding on it with rbind, and then can write out the RDS again.

```
(my_start_data <- data.frame(x=letters[1:3])) 
# ! this could have been loaded from an RDS via readRDS instead of being defined in code

(new_record = "xyz")

(bigger <- rbind(my_start_data,new_record))

saveRDS(object = bigger,
      file = "whatever.RDS")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to successfully add the new record. However, the same record gets added after every other record in the original file. So like in my case I get A, D, B, D  C, D...etc, but I should only see one new record of D.

Comment: Did you add a loop or other funky things ? as you can see in my example, the expected behaviour is a single new recor dat the end, there is nothing in my example that would cause duplication. I expect you added more code that introduced such behaviour. code that I can't see to comment on ...

Comment: your RDS contents is of unkown type. what is its class, what is its structure?  I made a reasonable assumption that it was a matrix or data.frame, but if it was some sort of list perhaps it would fail in the way you describe

Comment: Nothing at all except that instead of my_start_data <- data.frame(x=letters[1:3]), I put my_start_data <- readRDS("my_rds_dataframe.rds")

Comment: I check by typing typeof(my_start_data) and it shows [1] "list" and class(my_start_data) shows [1] "data.frame"

Comment: The dataframe is a single column of strings.

Comment: if its a dataframe then rbinding a final record will not interleave that record. Or can you provide a reproducible example of that happening ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254315/discussion-between-nir-graham-and-gkc).